# Salt Lake City driving in winter

Tags: driving, winter, skiing, utah

I plan to visit Salt Lake City this winter for a few weeks starting at Christmas. I'm renting a car and I was wondering if I should be aware of any specific regulations and issues while driving in winter.

- Would the rental cars typically offer winter tyres?
- Is the snow cleared often?
- Do I need an AWD/4WD to reach ski resorts e.g. Deer Valley, Park City?
- Do I need special winter lights?

For reference I'm based in the UK and will be travelling to ski resorts in the SL area.  I've never driven in the US, though I have in many other countries.

Comment: Welcome to Travel.SE!  You may get better results if you include the specific ski resorts you're considering;  the answer may depend on whether the resort is accessible via a major 4-lane highway or via a 2-lane back road.

Comment: Thanks @MichaelSeifert  Just added some, though I was hoping instead to choose the ski resorts around what was feasible...

Comment: Roads you would think of as motorways and A-roads are cleared more-or-less continuously during snowfall. It might take several hours to a day to get all the residential streets cleared after a big storm. But generally if it is not actually snowing at the moment, you can probably go out and drive.

Comment: There's no problem at all.

Comment: @MichaelSeifert - which ski slope were you thinking of near SLC that is accessible by a 4-lane highway ??

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I've flown into SLC Airport 3 times in the winter to ski at the resorts in Park City and once for Deer Valley and have rented a car each time. I've never had a problem with driving due to the snow.

- Would the rental cars typically offer winter tyres? - The rental cars
  I have rented have all come with basic all-season tires.
- Is the snow cleared often? - Yes, on the roads that you will be taking
  as a tourist between your airport, your hotel, the ski resorts and main tourism areas.
- Do I need an AWD/4WD to reach ski resorts e.g. Deer Valley, Park
  City? - No, but AWD/4WD would make driving safer if it is snowing during
  your drive.
- Do I need special winter lights? - No